# How to implement lazy loading in DataTable of PrimeReact

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading, primereact

I try to implement the lazy option of the `DataTable`. In the [official example](https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/#/datatable/lazy), only the `onPage` event is being used. But what if I need to use **column filters**, **paging** and **sorting** together? Is this the workflow which I need to develop?

1. client collects all sort, filter, paging in a `parameter list`
2. client send the `parameter list` to the backend
3. backend filters the data according to the `parameter list`
4. backend sends the new data to the client
5. client updates the datatable by updating the state with the new updated data

If this is the workflow, then how do I do that since I don't see any global event which collects all the parameters from the `DataTable`.

I've created a [test case](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-water-rh3ko?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) where the `CarService` class supposed to filter the data based on the event parameters all together. Consider this `CarService` as the backend.

**App**

```
export class App extends Component<{}, State> {
    carService = new CarService();

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
        cars: this.carService.getCars()
        };
    }

    onSort = (event: any) => {
        this.setState({ cars: this.carService.getFilteredCars(event) });
    };

    onPage = (event: any) => {
        this.setState({ cars: this.carService.getFilteredCars(event) });
    };

    onFilter = (event: any) => {
        this.setState({ cars: this.carService.getFilteredCars(event) });
    };

    render() {
        return (
        <div className="App">
            <DataTable
            value={this.state.cars}
            paginator={true}
            lazy={true}
            rows={2}
            rowsPerPageOptions={[2, 4]}
            onSort={this.onSort}
            onPage={this.onPage}
            onFilter={this.onFilter}
            >
            <Column field="vin" header="Vin" filter sortable />
            <Column field="year" header="Year" filter sortable />
            </DataTable>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**CarService**

```
export class CarService {
    cars = [
        { vin: "aaa", year: 1980 },
        { vin: "bbb", year: 1981 },
        { vin: "ccc", year: 1982 },
        { vin: "ccc", year: 1983 },
        { vin: "csdd", year: 1984 },
        { vin: "cgg", year: 1982 },
        { vin: "cyy", year: 1982 }
    ];

    getCars() {
        return this.cars;
    }

    getFilteredCars(filter: string) {
        // filter the cars based on the filter
        // an example filter could be: ?name=TestName&page=1
        return this.cars;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**[UPDATE] for PrimeReact version < 3.x:**

[PrimeReact DataTable](https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/#/datatable) (set in [lazy](https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/#/datatable/lazy) mode) has `onLazyLoad` event which is called in the following cases

- when the current page number (or page size) is changed,
- when any of defined column filters (actually inputs) are changed,
- when sort direction of any column (where sorting is enabled) is changed.

Datatable with `onLazyLoad` event can be declared, for example, like this

```
<DataTable value={this.state.cars} paginator={true}  lazy={true}
           rows={5} rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 20]} 
           totalRecords={this.state.totalRecords}
           onLazyLoad={this.onLazyLoad} ... >
```

where `onLazyLoad` function can be

```
onLazyLoad = (event) => {
    console.log("On Lazy load event", event);
    this.carservice.getLazyCars(event)...
}
```

and where `event` parameter/object has the following properties

- **filters** - key-value map of column filters
- **first** - page number
- **multiSortMeta** - key-value map if sorting is enabled for multiple columns simultaneously,
- **rows** - number of rows per one page,
- **sortField** - sort field name
- **sortOrder** - sort order of sort field (1-ascending, -1 descending)

You can find more details [here](https://4youngpadawans.com/primereact-lazy-table-filtering/) (with some other features demystified).

**[UPDATE] for PrimeReact version > 3.x:**

`onLazyLoad` event is removed from the library. Now relevant "lazy params" mentioned above are accessible via datatable's `state` property.

Add a reference to datatable

```
<DataTable ref={(el) => this.datatable = el} ... >
```

and retrieve "lazy params" (filters, sortField, sortOrder, first, multiSortMeta)  from `this.datatable.state` object when you need them. For example

```
onPage = (event) => {
    console.log("Data table state", this.datatable.state)
    //get filtered data using lazy params
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the `onLazyLoad` event doesn't exists in the library and documentation I think.

Comment: I've used it in project a year ago or so. Check out link with examples. Although its possible they removed it recently.

Comment: @KorkiKorkig, since onLazyLoad event is removed from the latest Primereact versions, I've updated my answer with a solution that might help you achieve what you want.

Comment: @DusanKovacevic Thank you for the PrimeReact version > 3.x example; it was a tremendous help since I couldn't find it in the official documentation.